# Extract longest block of continuous non-null values from each row in Pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a Pandas data frame structured similarly to the following:

```
data = {
    'A' : [5.0, np.nan, 1.0],
    'B' : [7.0, np.nan, np.nan],
    'C' : [9.0, 2.0, 6.0],
    'D' : [np.nan, 4.0, 9.0],
    'E' : [np.nan, 6.0, np.nan],
    'F' : [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    'G' : [np.nan, np.nan, 8.0]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data,
    index=['11','22','33']
)
```

From each row, I would like to extract the longest continuous block of non-null values and append them to a list.

So the following values from these rows:

```
row11: [5,7,9]    
row22: [2,4,6]    
row33: [6,9]
```

Giving me a list of values:

```
[5.0, 7.0, 9.0, 2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 6.0, 9.0]
```

My current approach uses `iterrows()` `first_valid_index()` and `last_valid_index()`:

```
mylist = []
for i, r in df.iterrows():
    start = r.first_valid_index()
    end = r.last_valid_index()
    mylist.extend(r[start: end].values)
```

This works fine when the valid digits are blocked together such as `row11` and `row22`. However my approach falls down when digits are interspersed with null values such as in `row33`. In this case, my approach extracts the entire row as the first and last index contain non-null values. My solution (incorrectly) outputs a final list of:

```
[5.0, 7.0, 9.0, 2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 1.0, nan, 6.0, 9.0, nan, nan, 8.0]
```

I have the following questions:
1.) How can I combat the error I'm facing in the example of `row33`?
2.) Is there a more efficient approach than using `iterrows()`? My actual data has many thousands of rows. While it isn't necessarily too slow, I'm always wary of resorting to iteration when using Pandas.

Answer (score 2):

One option using a [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to get the stretches of non-NA and [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) to filter the longest:

```
def get_longest(s):
    m = s.isna()
    return max(s[~m].groupby(m.cumsum()),
               key=lambda x: len(x[1])
              )[1].dropna().tolist()

out = df.apply(get_longest, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
11    [5.0, 7.0, 9.0]
22    [2.0, 4.0, 6.0]
33         [6.0, 9.0]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

With [`numpy.ma.masked_invalid`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ma.masked_invalid.html) and [`numpy.ma.clump_unmasked`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ma.clump_unmasked.html) functions to split a row into continuous slices of *non-nan* values and select slice with largest length:

```
res = df.apply(lambda x: x[max(np.ma.clump_unmasked(np.ma.masked_invalid(x.values)),
                               key=lambda sl: sl.stop - sl.start)].tolist(), axis=1)
```

---

```
11    [5.0, 7.0, 9.0]
22    [2.0, 4.0, 6.0]
33         [6.0, 9.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
m = df.notna().cumsum(axis=1)

m1 = m.sub(m.where(df.isna()).ffill(axis=1).fillna(0))
m2 = m1.max(axis=1)

df.where(m1.where(m1.eq(m2,axis=0)).apply(lambda x: x.bfill(limit = int(m2.loc[x.name] - 1)),axis=1).notna()).stack().groupby(level=0).agg(list)
```

Output:

```
11    [5.0, 7.0, 9.0]
22    [2.0, 4.0, 6.0]
33         [6.0, 9.0]
```